# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Messaging"

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

recently updated my packages and added a new one and now can't do pod install because I get this error:

`[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Messaging":
In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
Firebase/Messaging (= 10.19.0)

In Podfile:
RNFBMessaging (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging`) was resolved to 18.8.0, which depends on
Firebase/Messaging (= 10.20.0)

You have either:

- changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/Messaging` inside your development pod `RNFBMessaging`.
  You should run `pod update Firebase/Messaging` to apply changes you've made.`

This are my packages:

`"dependencies": { "@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods": "^7.23.3", "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.3", "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.7.3", "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6", "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9", "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.18", "iban": "^0.0.14", "install": "^0.13.0", "npm": "^10.2.5", "react": "18.2.0", "react-native": "^0.73.1", "react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.6", "react-native-date-picker": "^4.3.4", "react-native-document-picker": "^9.1.0", "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.5", "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0", "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.14.0", "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.0", "react-native-mmkv": "^2.11.0", "react-native-pdf": "^6.7.3", "react-native-permissions": "^4.0.1", "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1", "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.2", "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.8.1", "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0", "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0", "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3" },`

Tried to do a pod intall, pod intall --repo-update, pod update FirebaseCoreExtension, pod update Firebase/Messaging and tried changing manually in the lock file but seems to not work (not Sur eif changed correctly in pod file manually)

Comment: You have incompatible versions. You can use only one version of each "pod/subpod/lib". You have a conflict there, because RNFBMessaging needs a 10.20.0 of Firebase/Messaging and you are trying also to have the 10.19.0 (which I guess is `"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.7.3"`). Try if possible to find a "common working" version of Messaing.